# Node.js reference cycle

Tags: node.js, reference, cycle

I have two classes, Account and Character. An account can have multiple characters, but a character only belongs to one account.

```
class Account {
    constructor(){
        this.characters = // Array of chars
        this.selectedChar = // a character object
    }
}

class Character {
    constructor(account){
        this.account = account;
    }   
}
```

Now I have what I believe to be a reference cycle. The account will have a reference to a character, and that character will have a reference back to that account. Now my question is whether this will cause performance/memory issues, and if so, if I can do this another way.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem with such a cycle.

Comment: There is no problem with mutual references.  The garbage collector is smart enough to deal with circular references.